# How to get item[0] from "listview.ItemsSource" on universal(wpf)

Tags: c#, wpf, win-universal-app

```
lstvideo.ItemsSource = await GetVideo(_link.Link, "");    
var t = lstvideo.ItemsSource as Model.Video;
```

How to get `t[0]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (if i got you right):

```
    var x = t.First();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Model.Video video = lstvideo.ItemsSource.First();
```